# unable to find Prime number using Continue control flow

Tags: c

i wrote continue which brings back control to iteration and until the remainder is not zero so output should be printed. but it is not . why ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
  int n,i;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=2;i<n;i++)
  {
    if(n%i!=0)
    {
      continue;
      printf("prime\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Run the code in a debugger if you don’t see the problem. Go line by line. See what it does. Also please indent code properly always, it helps seeing things better. Think about the code. When can you get to the printf clause?

Comment: means ? what should i do. i am new in programming . please teach me sir.

Comment: Start your debugger. Click on a button that takes you to debug mode. Step forward. Continue stepping and see what your code does.

Comment: i am using ubuntu . how to stART  debugger

Comment: You might want to read this introduction tutorial to GCC and how to use the debugger http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/. In two minutes you will know how to debug your program with the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Can you spot the difference?

```
int main(void)
{
  int n,i;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=2;i<n;i++)
  {
    if(n%i!=0)
    {
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("not prime\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }
printf("prime\n");
}
```

Comment: This code is naughty: no error check on `scanf`, running `i` to `n`, prefer `if (n % i)`?

Comment: @Bathsheba - hair splitting - the question is not about the sprintf. it is only the slightly modified OPs code

Comment: I disagree. Not checking the return value of `scanf` is reprehensible.

Comment: @Bathsheba I disagree. If you disagree - write your own answer